# I got an error while uploading the seed data?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

In a .net core project, I got this error from seed data attachments and could not solve it. I would be glad if you could help.

"**System.InvalidOperationException: 'No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' method or by using 'AddDbContext' on the application service provider. If 'AddDbContext' is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.'*
*

Below is my startup file, seed file and DbContext file.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using BuyfiletBusiness.Abstract;
using BuyfiletBusiness.Concrete;
using BuyfiletData.Abstract;
using BuyfiletData.Concrete.EfCore;
using BuyfiletEntity.bagla;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace BuyfiletWeb
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; } 

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ShopContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:SqlConStr"].ToString(),
                o =>
                {
                    o.MigrationsAssembly("BuyfiletData");
                }));
            services.AddIdentity<UserEntity, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ShopContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders(); 
            services.AddScoped<IProductRepository, EfCoreProductRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IProductService, ProductManager>();
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                SeedDatabase.Seed();
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
using AlisverisagiEntity;
using AlisverisagiEntity.EntityModels;
using BuyfiletData.Concrete.EfCore.Seeds;
using BuyfiletEntity.bagla;
using BuyfiletEntity.EntityModels.Category;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace BuyfiletData.Concrete.EfCore
{
    public class ShopContext:IdentityDbContext<UserEntity>
    {
        public ShopContext()
        {

        }
        public ShopContext(DbContextOptions<ShopContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }
        public DbSet<UserEntity> UserModels { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public DbSet<BasicCategory> Categories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<MainCategory> MainCategories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<SubCategory> SubCategories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UserEntity> UserEntities { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Childs> Childs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Grandchilds> Grandchilds { get; set; }
     

      

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<ProductCategory>().HasKey(c => new
            {c.BasicCategoryId, c.ProductId,c.MainCategoryId,c.SubCategoryId}); 
            
            
        
           
        

        }
    }
}
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using AlisverisagiEntity.EntityModels;
using BuyfiletEntity.EntityModels.Category;

namespace BuyfiletData.Concrete.EfCore
{
   public static class SeedDatabase
    {
        public static void Seed()
        {
            var context = new ShopContext();
            context.Products.AddRange(products);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        private static Product[] products =
        {
            new Product()
            {
                Id = 1, StockCode = "5484959", Label = "Samsung S6", Status = 1,
                Brand = "Samsung Galaxy M51 128 GB (Samsung Türkiye Garantili)", IsOptionedProduct = 1,
                IsOptionOfAProduct = 2400, MarketPrice = 2600, BuyingPrice = "2400", Price = 2400, Tax = 14,
                CurrencyAbbr = "tl", RebateType = 1, Rebate = 200, MoneyOrder = 300, StockAmount = 5, StockType = "cm",
                Warranty = 200,
                Picture1Path = new Uri("https://productimages.hepsiburada.net/s/43/550/10756209672242.jpg/format:webp"),
                Picture2Path = new Uri("https://productimages.hepsiburada.net/s/43/550/10756209672242.jpg/format:webp"),
                Picture3Path = new Uri("https://productimages.hepsiburada.net/s/43/550/10756209672242.jpg/format:webp"),
                Picture4Path = new Uri("https://productimages.hepsiburada.net/s/43/550/10756209672242.jpg/format:webp"),
                Picture5Path = new Uri("https://productimages.hepsiburada.net/s/43/550/10756209672242.jpg/format:webp"),
                Picture6Path = new Uri("https://productimages.hepsiburada.net/s/43/550/10756209672242.jpg/format:webp"),
                Dm3 = 2554,
                Details =
                    "Samsung Galaxy M51 128 GB (Samsung Türkiye Garantili Samsung Galaxy M51 128 GB (Samsung Türkiye Garantili",
                Point = 15.8, Variety = "kırmızı", Size = "25", Color = "siyah", Gender = "erkek",
            },
            new Product()
            {
                Id = 2, StockCode = "5465465456", Label = "Samsung S6", Status = 1,
                Brand = "Samsung Galaxy M51 128 GB (Samsung Türkiye Garantili)", IsOptionedProduct = 1,
                IsOptionOfAProduct = 2400, MarketPrice = 2600, BuyingPrice = "2400", Price = 2400, Tax = 14,
                CurrencyAbbr = "tl", RebateType = 1, Rebate = 200, MoneyOrder = 300, StockAmount = 5, StockType = "cm",
                Warranty = 200,
                Picture1Path = new Uri("https://productimages.hepsiburada.net/s/43/550/10756209672242.jpg/format:webp"),
                Picture2Path = new Uri("https://productimages.hepsiburada.net/s/43/550/10756209672242.jpg/format:webp"),
                Picture3Path = new Uri("https://productimages.hepsiburada.net/s/43/550/10756209672242.jpg/format:webp"),
                Picture4Path = new Uri("https://productimages.hepsiburada.net/s/43/550/10756209672242.jpg/format:webp"),
                Picture5Path = new Uri("https://productimages.hepsiburada.net/s/43/550/10756209672242.jpg/format:webp"),
                Picture6Path = new Uri("https://productimages.hepsiburada.net/s/43/550/10756209672242.jpg/format:webp"),
                Dm3 = 2554,
                Details =
                    "Samsung Galaxy M51 128 GB (Samsung Türkiye Garantili Samsung Galaxy M51 128 GB (Samsung Türkiye Garantili",
                Point = 15.8, Variety = "kırmızı", Size = "25", Color = "siyah", Gender = "erkek",
            },
            new Product()
            {
                Id = 3, StockCode = "5484959", Label = "Samsung S6", Status = 1,
                Brand = "Samsung Galaxy M51 128 GB (Samsung Türkiye Garantili)", IsOptionedProduct = 1,
                IsOptionOfAProduct = 2400, MarketPrice = 2600, BuyingPrice = "2400", Price = 2400, Tax = 14,
                CurrencyAbbr = "tl", RebateType = 1, Rebate = 200, MoneyOrder = 300, StockAmount = 5, StockType = "cm",
                Warranty = 200,
                Picture1Path = new Uri("https://productimages.hepsiburada.net/s/43/550/10756209672242.jpg/format:webp"),
                Picture2Path = new Uri("https://productimages.hepsiburada.net/s/43/550/10756209672242.jpg/format:webp"),
                Picture3Path = new Uri("https://productimages.hepsiburada.net/s/43/550/10756209672242.jpg/format:webp"),
                Picture4Path = new Uri("https://productimages.hepsiburada.net/s/43/550/10756209672242.jpg/format:webp"),
                Picture5Path = new Uri("https://productimages.hepsiburada.net/s/43/550/10756209672242.jpg/format:webp"),
                Picture6Path = new Uri("https://productimages.hepsiburada.net/s/43/550/10756209672242.jpg/format:webp"),
                Dm3 = 2554,
                Details =
                    "Samsung Galaxy M51 128 GB (Samsung Türkiye Garantili Samsung Galaxy M51 128 GB (Samsung Türkiye Garantili",
                Point = 15.8, Variety = "kırmızı", Size = "25", Color = "siyah", Gender = "erkek",
            }
        };
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Sedat Sayer,you should following the [tutorials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/working-with-sql?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio).

Answer (score 0):

It's clearly that you instantiate a new instance of `ShopContext` using its parameterless constructor and it really does not have any `OnConfiguring` code. Hence the error.

In the context of `Startup.Configure` method, you can obtain the configured `ShopContext` correctly via the `IApplicationBuilder` like this:

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
  using(var sc = app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope())
  using(var dbContext = sc.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ShopContext>())
  {
      //check if database does not exist
      //we do this one time only to avoid Seed is run each time debugging
      if(!dbContext.Database.CanConnect()){
        //for testing only, do not use for production because then 
        //you usually need a true migration.
        dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
        SeedDatabase.Seed(dbContext);
      }   
  }            
  app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
```

Modify your `SeedDatabase.Seed` method to accept a `ShopContext` instead:

```
public static void Seed(ShopContext context)
{
   context.Products.AddRange(products);
   context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand how to do it. Can you explain it in a little more detail?

Comment: @SedatSayer it's fairly clear, there are just 2 places in your code to update. Look at it carefully again, you'll understand.

Comment: I did what he said and then I got this error

System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot resolve scoped service' BuyfiletData.Concrete.EfCore.ShopContext 'from root provider.'

Comment: @SedatSayer see my updated code. I forgot that the scoped service cannot be created that way.

Comment: @SedatSayer BTW, if somehow your db has been created before, you need to delete it first. The code above has an `if` to protect the seeding code from running multiple times. Otherwise you can temporarily modify it so that it runs once, then modify it back. Again, we usually use true data migration for production (maybe in combination with modifying the migration files directly or executing sql script).

Comment: It worked fine, but Seed data was not added to the db.

Comment: @SedatSayer as I said above, has your db been created before? the call `Seed` is guarded by the `if` which is run only when the db has not been created yet. Be sure that (by debugging) the `Seed` method is called. It would be strange that even if it's called, not any data is created. Or at least there should be some updating error.

Comment: I deleted the database and nothing changed. Seed data is not included.

Comment: @SedatSayer can you confirm that after that retry, the database is recreated OK, the `Seed` method is called, no error but seeded data is not created?

Comment: I ask you to confirm all the above because I doubt that the connection string may point to another database. There is no way the code in `Seed` running but no data is created, at least if something wrong, there should be an error thrown here.

Comment: Yes, data did not come. And I called it by typing your code in the Startup file. The web page opens without any problems, but test data is not added.
If I ask, can you check my codes above? I may have missed a place.

Comment: @SedatSayer the code in your `Seed` method (after modified following my solution) is fine. How do you know the data is not created? could you open that product table in your db directly? that's how you check it. If your webpage has another view to show the products but you see nothing, that's possibly another issue of that view.

Comment: No, when I check the database, the table rows appear blank. No data has been added.

Comment: @SedatSayer I'm not sure if there is something special configured to your models but by default the `Product.Id` is auto-incremented (auto-gen, by convention). So if the code runs, it would throw exception because you set explicit values for all `Product` items (Id = 1, Id = 2, ...). So I really doubt that the code does not run at all. (otherwise an exception would be thrown).

Comment: Unfortunately, there is another problem that I missed.

Comment: @SedatSayer is it related to the cause making no data created? If possible, update your question with that so that I may help. If it's another issue, your original issue (asked in this question) might have already been solved by what I've provided here.

Comment: The problem is with the seed data not being processed. Everything works fine but seed data is not processed.